# ERROR: Permission to xxx.git denied to xxx, fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh

I was rejected when pushing a new branch to the remote repo,

```
ERROR: Permission to xxx.git denied to <username>.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is the company repo not under my username, but I can clone and pull things from it. The ssh key was set okay following the instructions on github.

When running

```
git remote -v
```

I can see:

```
origin  git@<company name>:xxx.git (fetch)
origin  git@<company name>:xxx.git (push)
```

When running:

```
ssh -T  git@<company username>.com.
```

I got:

```
Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Is shell an issue here? Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: maybe you only have read-only access or not have permission to create branches ?

Comment: yeah, that could be the issue, thanks